# Is there outerWidth height equivalent in dart( border, margine, padding inclusive element size)

Tags: dart

I would like to find the border, margin and padding inclusive size of an element. jquery's outerWidth, outerHeight methods equivalent.

Currently, I'm using a silly code like below.
What is the real solution?

### Edit:

Neither the code I originally posted, that rounded the width and height, or marginEdge do the trick. Browsers uses the precision of double to draw elements and there sometimes the difference of 21px and 20.6px matters.

### Edit2

getBoundingClientRect() seems to returns border and padding inclusive size, commented lines involving those out and added to toDouble() to avoid int is not a subclass of double error.
Revised code:

```
Rectangle outerRect(HtmlElement e,[bool include_margin = false]) {
  HtmlElement c = e.clone(true);
  c.style
    ..display = 'absolate'
    ..top = '-1000000px';
  document.body.append(c);
  var r = c.getBoundingClientRect();
  //rounding down causes troubles downstream
  //r.width can return int then,
  // int cannot be assigned to double
  double width = r.width.toDouble();
  double height = r.height.toDouble();
  int parse(String s){
    if(s == '') return 0;
    if(s.contains('px')){
      var m = new RegExp('[0-9]+').firstMatch(s);
      if(m == null) return 0;
      return int.parse(m.group(0));
    }
    throw "Unexpected string ${s}";
  }
  var s = c.style;
  if(include_margin) {
    width += parse(s.marginRight);
    width += parse(s.marginLeft);
//  width += parse(s.paddingLeft);
//  width += parse(s.paddingRight);

    height += parse(s.marginTop);
    height += parse(s.marginBottom);
//  height += parse(s.paddingBottom);
//  height += parse(s.paddingTop);

//  height += parse(s.borderTop);
//  height += parse(s.borderBottom);
//  height += parse(s.paddingBottom);
//  height += parse(s.paddingTop);
  }
  r = new Rectangle(-1,-1,width,height);
  c.remove();
  return r;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure, but isn't that what marginEdge on the Element gives you?

Comment: Thanks, just the thing I needed. With marginEdge, the element needs to be in the dom tree, else it returns zero initialized Rectangle and the value returned is rounded to the nearest integer. Apart from those, exactly the thing I needed.

Comment: Thanks for posting and marginEdge does exactly what my original code did. So it's a bit wrong to remove the answer status from your post, but I realized I needed sub-zero precision to make my elements look the same size(so, rounding was a mistake/bug to begin with).